# Как реализовать анимацию падения снежинок на заднем фоне всего приложения?

Tags: android, background

Делаю новогоднее обновление. Хочется сделать анимацию падения снежинок на всех экранах приложения на заднем фоне.

Как это можно реализовать, учитывая что экраны разные?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возьмите [такую имплементацию](https://github.com/JetradarMobile/android-snowfall)

Лейаут будет примерно такой:

```
<com.jetradarmobile.snowfall.SnowfallView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:snowflakesNum="250"
      app:snowflakeAlphaMin="150"
      app:snowflakeAlphaMax="255"
      app:snowflakeAngleMax="5"
      app:snowflakeSizeMin="8dp"
      app:snowflakeSizeMax="32dp"
      app:snowflakeSpeedMin="4"
      app:snowflakeSpeedMax="12"
      app:snowflakesFadingEnabled="true"
      app:snowflakesAlreadyFalling="false"
      app:snowflakeImage="@drawable/snowflake"/>
```

Пример анимации ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]